# Geolocation won't be displayed in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, openweathermap

I am using a openweather api to display the weather of the user's city. I begin by using the geolocation function to find the latitude and longitude of the user. That data is then passed in the variable api. The console keeps displaying a value of undefined. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 var lat;
 var long; 

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    long = position.coords.longitude; 


  var api='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+long+'&appid=myapi';

  $.getJSON(api,function(data){
 var city= data.name; 

  console.log(api);
  console.log(city);
  });

  });

}

});
```

Comment: Have you tested your API key? put the url in the browser see what comes up? 

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=-33.8657305&lon=151.20732999999998&appid=myapi

If it returns something like this: 
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}

then you need to double check your appid

Comment: Is this the exact code? Maybe you've forgotten to replace the myapi with the actual appId you got from openweather. I'm asking just in case.

Comment: This is the exact code minus the actual api key number.

Comment: Cool, did you test the URL in the browser? And also put a console.log(data) before var city=data.name , see what's being returned from the service.

Comment: Here is a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/sibraza/pen/VjYwWK?editors=1111

Comment: The url works. When I removed the geolocation function and tried alert(data.lat) it brought the right latitude. I'm not sure where the error is?

Comment: have a look into the answer

Answer (score 0):

So change the code for getJSON to this :

```
$.getJSON(api,{})
.done(function(data){
console.log(data.name);
})
.fail(function(err){
console.log(err.responseText);
});
```

and check the console for the actual error